# Second derivative of SmoothKernelDistribution PDF?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, interpolation, distributions

Does anyone know why I can't seem to get a second derivative of this interpolating function `f`?  In this example, `h[x]` is zero for all `x`.

```
data = Join[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[-3, 1], 100], RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[3, 1], 100]];
f = PDF[SmoothKernelDistribution[data]];
g = f';
h = g';
Plot[{f[x], g[x], h[x]}, {x, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: You might try KernelMixtureDistribution to avoid the piecewise linear limitation

Answer (score 4):

If you plot f, f', and f'' over a much smaller range, the answer will be obvious:  the interpolation function f is piecewise linear, f' is piecewise constant (i.e., a step function), and f'' is identically zero within each interval.

Comment: Oops, I backspaced in the window and the message got messed up.