# Find Background noise in Image

Tags: image-processing, image

I have a set of 12 Images of a time dependent process. The Images also contain a static noise, which I want to get rid of. I had an idea to do that manually by looking at differences of images and finding common pixel positions, I was able to extract the something, which looked like the noise, but it did not help in the end.

What else can I do?

EDIT:

Here are all pictures in the right order. You may notice the static noise in the lower left and lower right corner. *I am especially interested in a method, which uses the correlative information among these.*

```
images = {Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/Npw8Z.png"],
   Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/xiePv.png"],
   Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/IuArl.png"],
   Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDDLX.png"],
   Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/Twiw5.png"],
   Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJYt0.png"],
   Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDrO0.png"],
   Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/RtWVe.png"],
   Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggM1i.png"],
   Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0xBt.png"],
   Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/YlDoP.png"],
   Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBITO.png"]};
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: The last image itself seems like a good picture of the noise.

Comment: To use it as the noise would be the plan B. But there is still useful information on it.

Comment: The last frame actually has a lot of what i suspect is real data in the middle that's comparable brightness to the quote noise.  Frame 11 might be useful to work with.  Are you just after looking pleasing or do you need to analyze the result?

Comment: I don't need to do anything, nobody is after me. If I was looking for pleasing, plan B would be sufficient.  But I am personally interested in a more accurate solution, that involves looking at correlative information.

Comment: Are these the full size uncompressed images from your camera?  I believe hot pixel detection and compensation works best with "RAW" format data.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to the raw data. The pictures had been delivered in 24-bit BMP.

Comment: Can you post the remaining images? I would try to fit a diffusion function to the bright spot on the centre, subtract that to all images and average to get the static noise.

Comment: Expanding atom cloud? Why exactly do you want to get rid of the noise? Is there quantitative information you'd like to extract from the image series?

Comment: @Quantum_Oli Yes. I needed to find the center of mass, to make a radial projection of all particles, in order to find a radial density function for each image. I don't know if it's a good strategy, but worth trying. I will upload the rest in a minute.

Comment: Indeed, can you upload the remaining images?

Comment: @blochwave Done

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Previous answers use morphological methods and various smooth filters to get rid of the noise. Such a way may throw away important information. Since the noise distribution is [known](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/124060/object-detection-in-a-low-contrast-image/124081#124081), I suggest to utilize the method from theory of probability. If we estimate the noise distribution, we can can refine the signal by using Bayes' theorem. We assume that the noise PDF is the combination of Gaussian modes. First, let's plot the first image histogram

```
image = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/Npw8Z.png"];
imdata = ImageData[image];
data = Flatten[imdata];
{nRow, nCol} = Dimensions[imdata];
n = Length[data];
sk = SmoothKernelDistribution[data];
sh[x_] := PDF[sk, x];
Plot[sh[x], {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

And answer the question - how many Gaussian components describe the histogram? This question does not have [clear](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZZGTuAkF-Hw) answer. We can try some numerical experiment to find it. Let's write the Expectation-Maximization algorithm for arbitrary number of Gaussian modes in the mixture. You can find the example of the algorithm for three modes in [other](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28429/how-to-make-a-multi-peak-histogram-fitting/123814#123814) answer. I write the code here for arbitrary number of modes.

```
p[x_, μ_, σ_] := 1/(σ Sqrt[2 π]) Exp[-((x - μ)^2/(2 σ^2))];

ni = 5;
α = RandomReal[1/ni, ni - 1];
AppendTo[α, 1 - Total[α]];
μ = RandomReal[1, ni];
σ = RandomReal[1, ni];
```

where ni is the number of Gaussian in the mixture and α, μ and σ are random starting points. The main loop can be written as (it may not be optimal from the programming point of view):

```
μold = Total[μ];
μnew = 0;

While[Abs[μold - μnew] > 10^-3,

 μold = Total[μ];

 denom = Sum[p[data, μ[[i]], σ[[i]]]*α[[i]], {i, 1, ni}];

 ω = {};
 nn = {};

 Do[AppendTo[ω, p[data, μ[[i]], σ[[i]]]*α[[i]]/denom], {i, 1, ni}];
 Do[AppendTo[nn, Total[ω[[i]]]], {i, 1, ni}];

 α = nn/n;

 Do[μ[[i]] = (1/nn[[i]]) Total[ω[[i]]*data], {i, 1, ni}];
 Do[σ[[i]] = Sqrt[(1/nn[[i]]) Total[ω[[i]]*(data - μ[[i]])^2]], {i,1,ni}];

 μnew = Total[μ];

 Print[Abs[μold - μnew]];
]

res[x_] := Sum[α[[i]] p[x, μ[[i]], σ[[i]]], {i, 1, ni}]
```

where res[x] is the estimated distribution. I run cases for 2, 3, 4, 5 Gaussian modes and calculate L2 norm

```
Sqrt[NIntegrate[(res[x] - sh[x])^2, {x, 0, 1}]]
```

of the initial and estimated histograms. The result is shown below, where the first column is the number of modes

```
err = {{2, {0.9305624238000338`, 0.9313479851474045`, 
     0.9315706394559939`}}, {3, {0.3001499957482421`, 
     0.28225797805173036`, 
     0.34266514794304387`}}, {4, {0.19062005525627448`, 
     0.1897738119054123`, 
     0.19225727176562063`}}, {5, {0.17364508389127895`, 
     0.20755015809865515`, 0.1314936019036575`}}};
```

Because the starting point is random, I run the code a couple of times for each case. The more the better for the convergence study, but I run 3 times just for the example. Now, plot the averaged L2 norm

```
errm = Table[{err[[i]][[1]], Mean[err[[i]][[2]]]}, {i, 1, 4}]
ListPlot[errm, Joined -> True]
```

[image]

As you can see, the norm saturates with the number of modes and it looks like 5 modes is good enough. Plot the estimated histogram with 5 modes vs image histogram

```
Plot[{sh[x], res[x]}, {x, 0, 0.5}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

where the blue line corresponds to the initial histogram and the red line to the estimated

Now we have to define the noise. Let's print the amplitudes of the modes

```
α
{0.0665394, 0.487155, 0.164024, 0.205775, 0.0765071}
```

We can define noise as the fist 3 modes with the largest amplitude (largest because the noise in the background).

```
αs = Sort[α, Greater]    
i1 = Position[α, αs[[1]]][[1]][[1]];
i2 = Position[α, αs[[2]]][[1]][[1]];
i3 = Position[α, αs[[3]]][[1]][[1]];
```

Define variables with the noise parameters.

```
α1 = α[[i1]];
α2 = α[[i2]];
α3 = α[[i3]];

σ1 = σ[[i1]];
σ2 = σ[[i2]];
σ3 = σ[[i3]];

μ1 = μ[[i1]];
μ2 = μ[[i2]];
μ3 = μ[[i3]];
```

Plot the noise PDF vs the image PDF

```
Plot[{sh[x], α1 p[x, μ1, σ1] + α2 p[x, μ2, σ2] + α3 p[x, μ3, σ3]}, {x, 0, 0.5},
PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

where the blue line corresponds to the initial histogram and the red line to the noise histogram. Using Bayes' theorem, we can find the probability for pixel to be the noise

```
denom = Sum[p[imdata, μ[[i]], σ[[i]]]*α[[i]], {i, 1, ni}];

ωnoise = (p[imdata, μ1, σ1]*α1 + p[imdata, μ2, σ2]*α2 +
p[imdata, μ3, σ3]*α3)/denom;
```

where ωnoise is the probability. Plot the histogram of this probability.

```
Histogram[Flatten[ωnoise], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

As you can see the left part is the signal and the right the noise. Plot the 2D diagram of the noise probability.

```
Image[ωnoise]
```

[image]

where the white color corresponds to the high probability to be the noise. As you can see, there are some dark pixels at the left corner, may be it is also the signal, at least it has high probability to be the signal. Finally, remove pixels with the high (here 97%) probability to be the noise

```
imdatas = 
  Table[If[ωnoise[[i]][[j]] < 0.03, imdata[[i]][[j]], 0], {i, nRow}, {j, nCol}];
```

Plot the image without the noise

```
Image[imdatas]
```

[image]

and plot the 3D figure

```
ListPlot3D[imdatas]
```

[image]

As you can see the image is generally clean from the noise. There are some pixels at the left corner which looks like the noise, but have high probability to be the signal.

Comment: awesome. thank you

Comment: You are welcome. Actually, you can improve the method by using Poisson like distribution. But the image shows intensity in arbitrary units. The possible way is to use  "scaled Poisson" distribution, but it is computationally intensive. The second way is to use Gaussian distribution with standard deviation depending on the mean N(mu, mu/s), where s is the scaling coefficient. This coefficient means the number of photon counts per a.u. You have to find maximum likelihood for this distribution with respect to "mu" and "s" and use it inside the EM algorithm. The result could be a more accurate.

Answer (score 5):

```
image = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/Npw8Z.png"];

ImageHistogram[image]
```

[image]

or in 3d:

```
ListPlot3D[ImageData[image]]
```

[image]

The total number of pixels above a threshold of 0.15 is:

```
Count[Flatten[ImageData[image]], a_ /; a > 0.15]
28125
```

which is `0.0915527 %` of the total pixel number (640*480).

So, let's select `0.15` as a reasonable threshold, remove the small spikes at the edges with `DeleteSmallComponents` and try:

```
binImage = Binarize[image, 0.2];
binImage2 = DeleteSmallComponents[binImage, 10];
newImage = ImageMultiply[image, binImage2]
```

[image]

The 3d histogram of the filtered image is:

[image]

Comment: Nice! I believe `binImage = Binarize[image, FindThreshold[image]];` automates the threshold value finding quite well

Comment: `FindThreshold[image] = 0.172549` is not far from my guess of `0.15` ... good idea ... I have only to find out how `FindThreshold ` works ...

Answer (score 4):

Since your question says what else can I do, I post this here since it's too large for a comment.

I tried different combinations to get rid of the noise but looking pixel by pixel was useless. Seems like there is some white noise also added to the mix so when you subtract the images you get mostly noise.

What I found useful, and not terribly difficult to get the radial distribution function from, is to binarize and subtract a constant from the images.

```
im1 = Import["http://s23.postimg.org/cdwfw2eqj/mot0000.png"];
im2 = Import["http://s27.postimg.org/o3944jtmb/mot0002.png"];
im11 = Import["http://s13.postimg.org/e3hanc0qf/mot0011.png"];

Animate[GaussianFilter[ImageSubtract[Binarize[#, a], 0.05], 
10] & /@ {im1, im2, im11}, {a, 0, .25}]
```

[image]

The edge of the white zone at a given `a` gives you the contour line at a given intensity. Recovering the radial density function from there should be easy.

Well, maybe not that easy since `EdgeDetect` doesn't work too well for low `a`

```
Animate[EdgeDetect[
    GaussianFilter[ImageSubtract[Binarize[#, a], 0.05], 
     15]] & /@ {im1, im2, im11}, {a, 0, .25}]
```

[image]

Maybe you like more a Laplacian filter?

```
    ImageAdjust[
   LaplacianFilter[
    GaussianFilter[ImageSubtract[Binarize[#, a], 0.05], 15], {2, 
     1}]] & /@ {im1, im2, im11}
```

Don't know why but the first gif reminds me of those atomic bombs films from the 40s.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can use 'BilateralFilter' or TotalVariationFilter no additinal steps needed.

```
BilateralFilter[#, 5, 0.2] & /@ images
```

> [image]

or

```
TotalVariationFilter[#, 0.2, Method -> "Gaussian"] & /@ images
```

> [image]

An alternative idea is to construct 3d image and clean up the top view... I hope it helps:

```
(*Construct 3d image with top view*)
img = Image3D[images, ViewPoint -> Top];
(*Adjust and rasterize*)
img2d = ImageAdjust[img] // Rasterize
```

> [image]

```
MedianFilter[RemoveBackground[img2d, {"Background", "Dark"}], 3]
```

> [image]